# Android WebView activity crashes :java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling View methods on another thread than the UI thread

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, webview

I have a custom android plugin for unity which opens a `Webview` activity. When I try to open the activity it crashes. When I try to initialise the `WebView`, below log statements appear from log cat.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling View methods on another thread than the UI thread.
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.createThreadException(WebViewChromium.java:252)
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.checkThread(WebViewChromium.java:267)  
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(WebViewChromium.java:163)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:661)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:596)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:579)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:566)
at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:556)
at com.vadrnet.unitysdk.MyWebViewClass.<init>(MyWebViewClass.java:31)
at com.vadrnet.unitysdk.WebViewActivity$1.run(WebViewActivity.java:207)
at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:5850)
at com.vadrnet.unitysdk.WebViewActivity.onCreate(WebViewActivity.java:205)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6582)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2532)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1494)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

My code for starting the activity via Unity Script is

```
AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
currentActivity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() =>
{
   AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.vadrnet.unitysdk.ManagerClass");
   AndroidJavaObject className = jc.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
   className.Call("click", currentActivity, url);
 }));
```

and the Click function in the Plugin is

```
 public void click(Activity root, String url){
    Intent intent = new  Intent(root, WebViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("url", url);
    root.startActivity(intent);
}
```

I couldn't get why the error occurs despite being opening the activity in the UI thread itself. Any help would be great.

Comment: Is this problem resolved for you?

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Any solutuion?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this bit of code may be it will be of help
please check this before posting
[QA link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255920/java-lang-illegalstateexception-calling-view-methods-on-another-thread-than-the)

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
    public void run() {
        // Code for WebView goes here
    }
});


// This code is BAD and will block the UI thread
webView.loadUrl("javascript:fn()");
while(result == null) {
  Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution by the web is

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // TODO Your code
        }
    });
```

When you do that [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140285/how-do-we-use-runonuithread-in-android) so see how to use `runOnUiThread` currently

Example on how to use it in Unity ([documentation link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaRunnable.html)):

```
void Start()
    {
        AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        activity.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(runOnUiThread));
    }

    void runOnUiThread()
    {
        Debug.Log("I'm running on the Java UI thread!");
    }
```

Another Example on how to use it in Unity: ([Link to source](https://forum.unity.com/threads/runonuithread-not-working-when-extending-unityplayeractivity.235088/))

```
UnityPlayer.currentActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
           // Run in Thread...
    }
});
```

But you can also use

```
UserContrl1_LOadDataMethod()
{
    string name = "";
    if(myObject.InvokeRequired)
    {
        myObject.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { name = textbox1.text; }));
    }
    if(name == "MyName")
    {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

[For more info you can use This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19483270/)